# Object oriented programming in Python: Mysterious Syntax Error - TV Object

Tags: python, object, methods, syntax-error

So I need to write a program that simulates a Television as an object for a challenge in a tutorial book on Python (Python for the Absolute Beginner, chapter 8). I figured most of the code would be similar to the Critter Caretaker program from that chapter. I don't yet know if this program will work once I fix the problem I'm about to present, because I can't get it to run.

Here is the code:

```
#TV Object

class TV(object):

    def __init__(self, volume = 50, channel = 1):
        self.volume = 50
        self.channel = 1
        print("You have turned on your TV")

    def change_channel(self, channel):
        print("This TV has three channels: News, Weather, and Soap Operas.")
        print("""
Which would you like to watch?
1 - News
2 - Weather
3 - Soap Operas    
    """)
        change = int(input(""))
        if change in range(1-3):
            channel = change
        return channel

    def set_volume(self, volume):
        print("The current volume is ", volume, ".")
        change = int(input("What volume level would you like (1-100)?:")
        if change in range(1-100):
                     volume = change
        return volume

    def watch(self, volume, channel):
         news = "Breaking News: U.S Senate to vote today on bill to use politicians for lab experiments."
         weather = "We're looking at a mostly sunny day with a slight chance of atomic anhiliation."
         soap = "John, I think I'm pregnant! And the father is your evil twin!"

         if channel == 1:
             program = news
         if channel == 2:
             program = weather
         if channel == 3:
             program = soap

         if volume == 70>:
            print(upper(program))
         elif volume == 30<:
              print(lower(program))
         else:
              print(program)

def main():
        tv = TV()

        choice = None
        while choice != "0":
            print \
            ("""
            0 - Turn it off
            1 - Change the channel
            2 - Set the volume
            3 - Watch TV
            """)

            choice = input("Choice: ")
            print()

            #exit
            if choice == "0":
                print("Good-bye.")

            #change the channel
            elif choice == "1":
                tv.change_channel(channel)

            #set volue
            elif choice == "2":
                tv.set_volume(volume)

            #watch TV
            elif choice == "3":
                tv.watch(volume, channel)

            #some unknown choice
            else:
                print("\nSorry but", choice, "isn't a valid choice.")



main()
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit
```

The error occurs in the set_volume method.

```
def set_volume(self, volume):
        print("The current volume is ", volume, ".")
        change = int(input("What volume level would you like (1-100)?:")
        if change in range(1-100):
                     volume = change
        return volume
```

Once I reach this 'if change in range(1-100):' line of code, the pyshell tells me that I made a Syntax Error right on the colon. It doesn't give me any more information about WHAT that error is.

Another oddity that has occurred is that, when writing the program, the auto spacing after I move to the next line from a colon seems off; like it's moving the cursor over too many spaces, as if it thinks that the code is meant for an invisible SUBcolon that came after the previous colon. At first I thought maybe I didn't finish a previous line of code, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

What is causing my syntax error?

P.S: If anyone else notices other problems with the code that will crop up once the syntax error is fixed, I would appreciate being told about them. I'm new to object programming and I could use all the help I can get.

Comment: You're missing a closing parentheses on this line: `change = int(input("What volume level would you like (1-100)?:")`

Comment: Also, range(1-100) does not do what you think it does.

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, your `range(1-100)` is incorrect. You want `range(1, 100)`. However, if you actually print -> `print(list(range(1, 100)))`, you will see that it actually only goes to `99`. So, you actually want `range(1, 101)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing parenthesis

```
# is
change = int(input("What volume level would you like (1-100)?:")
# Should be
change = int(input("What volume level would you like (1-100)?:"))
```

Also your calls to range should be use a comma to separate the first and second parameter being passed.

```
if change in range(1, 101):
    self.volume = change
```

Also should be noted that logic only works in python 2 as the behavior of `range` changes in python 3. In 2 `range` returns a list whereas in 3 it is a generator. To use the generator version of `range` in python 2 you must call `xrange` instead.

**EDIT**

You need to assign the results of the method back to the channel/volume attributes instead of using `return`. You can access them via the `self` parameter which is a reference to that particular instance of the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_volume(self, volume):
    print("The current volume is ", volume, ".")

    # missing paren at the end of this line
    change = int(input("What volume level would you like (1-100)?:")

    # range(1-100) gives (1 through -100). 
    # You want either range(1+100) range(1,101).
    if change in range(1-100):

    # keep your indentation consistent
        volume = change

    return volume
```

Additionally, your class variables won't work. Here's how I would write the function:

```
def set_volume(self):
    print("The current volume is ", self.volume, ".")
    new_volume = input("What volume level would you like (1-100)?:")
    if is_int(new_volume) and new_volume in range(1+100):
        self.volume = int(change)
```

and then down in main...

```
elif choice == "2":
    tv.set_volume()
```

What happens here is the class `TV` is the platonic ideal of something "TV-like". All TV's have a volume, and a volume knob. But you can't change the volume on a generic platonic `TV`.

So, you make an *instance*, a 'physical' manifestation of the generic `TV`. You assign this instance to the variable `tv`.

Now, when you call `tv.set_volume()`, this actually calls `TV.set_volume(self=tv)`. The `self` parameter is the physical instance. Using the self parameter, the functions can manipulate both volume and channel.